# jquery templates selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

I have a jquery template with N radio buttons and I need to select radio button with value that I pass after loading template from external html file(using jQuery.tmpl() method). Is there a good way of selection of radio button in template without multiple {{if}}, {{else}} statements, duplicate code and selectors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In what format is your data coming back from the server?  If it's a JSON array, could you do something like this?

html:

```
<script id="myTemplate" type="text/html">
    <input type="radio" value="${value}"{{if selected}} checked{{/if}}>${name}</input><br />
</script>

<div id="myDiv">
</div>
```

javascript:

```
var myData = [
    {name: 'test 1', value : 'radio1', selected : false},
    {name: 'test 2', value : 'radio2', selected : false},
    {name: 'test 3', value : 'radio3', selected : true},
    {name: 'test 4', value : 'radio4', selected : false}
];

$('#myTemplate').tmpl(myData).appendTo('#myDiv');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JbTwB/1/

Answer (score 1):

If you have the value of the desired radio, you could do something like:

```
jInstance.find('input[value=' + desiredValue + ']').attr('checked', true);
```

This assumes that `jInstance` is the newly-created copy of the template, and that `desiredValue` exactly matches the value of the radio button you'd like to be pre-selected.

If you only know part of the value, there are other jQuery selectors you can use to target that input.

If you're looking for a more general "form pre-filling" routine, you'll need to establish some kind of format for storing the set of pre-fill values, and a mapping from that format to the template. But it can be done, and it's not necessarily that hard, either.

Comment: I wrote without selectors!! I have a too big file(controller) that loads a big number of templates(views) and I'm trying to remove redundant selectors.

Comment: In order to manipulate a DOM element, you need to obtain a reference to the node. Generating that reference will require either: an ID (fastest, but comes with uniqueness constraints), or some more generalized selector. Unless you want to manipulate the markup as a giant string, perhaps with regexes. Which will perform terrible and is very fragile. Using a selector will avoid the use of duplicate code and lots of `if/else` blocks.

Comment: Perhaps you could pass the set of desired values to the server in the template request, and the server could modify the generated markup before the response is sent. But that approach is not javascript-based, and you'd need to re-tag the question to get answers.

Comment: why do I need to get ID? Example: {{if somevalue=="value1"}}<input name="option1" value="value1" checked="checked"/><input name="option2" value="value2"/>{{else}}<input name="option1" value="value1" /><input name="option2" value="value2" checked="checked"/>{{/if}}. Unfortunately, this code contains duplicates.

Comment: I think this is the wrong approach. Rather than rely on the templating engine to do the pre-selection, you should modify the newly-created instance of the template with the values of interest. That's a pretty standard pattern, and is both flexible and robust. It should also help reduce the giant size of the template, as well as increasing performance.

Comment: Ok, you've convinced me, but I still have a huge file that contains references to selectors to another external files:(((